# How to put static and media setting at the same time in Django

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-media

Hi i'm quite confuse on this, on how to put static and media in `urlpatterns` at the same time, I already understand that `static` is for css/javascript while `media` is for the user upload file, since then if I use the `{% static '<pathname>' %}` in html file but i'm referring on the media not on the css/javascript, is there a conflict or how django will understand that i'm targeting the media one?

here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    login,
    signup,
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', login, name = 'login'),
    path('signup/', signup, name = 'signup')
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS)
```

I already put the static and works perfectly but where I should but the media?

Answer (score 3):

In your `urls.py` you can do something like this for development

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatters = [
    # your url patterns here
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    # serve static and media files from development server
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

You don't need to use these settings when you have `DEBUG = False` in your `settings.py` file.

Also in your `settings.py` file, you should set the static files location and media files location because once you deploy this into production, Django will use these settings when you run `python manage.py collectstatic`.  Here is an example:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

=== EDIT to answer your question in the comment ===

When user generated content is uploaded (AKA media), a reference to that file's location is stored in the database.  So when your context is passed to the template you will automatically get an image object you can reference within your template.

You would do something like this

`<img src="{{ self.someimage.url }}" alt=""> # would give you the url path.`

I'm not sure of your context passed to the template, so you would need to take if from here or paste your view from the `views.py` file in your question.

Comment: then how can i access files in html? like example i will use the static files css/javascript how will django will understand that i'm trying to access static not media or vice-versa?

Comment: see my === EDIT === in my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) setting to build up a list of assets and then namespace the "media" folder.

ex:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    ("media", "/path/to/media/directory"),  
]
```

and use it like this in your templates

```
{% static "media/your_asset_file" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT in your settings file.

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

Then in your `urls.py` file
Simply add these line below the one you have for static files.

```
urlpatterns+=static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: I already know how to implement that, my question is that how to use both static and media in urlpatterns.

Comment: Django doesn't let you share media and static file directories. It'll raise an ImproperlyConfigured exception if you try do so. Media files should be accessed through /media and static files should be accessed through /static so you should have two url pattern entries one to handle static files and the other to handle media files. In your template, you can do e.g <img src="{{ object.filefield.url }}"/>, assuming you have it in the context.

Hope these answers your question.